# jQuery Login - What is the best practise for a login?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

I'm trying to improve my jQuery skills developing a litte website containing a login system.
I'm looking for the **best practise and most secure login system**.

So far

- I had a `login.html` having a `<form action="login.pl">`.
- On my `login.pl` I'm connecting to my database and if the user is valid I `print` a http-redirect to `home.html` adding my params (`?param1=val1&param2=val2`).
  [image]

Now I took a different way (at least for me a better looking way).

- I have a `login.html` doing an `$.ajax` request before submit.
- The ajax request calls my `login.pl`which is returning an json-sting containing a status.
- If the json-sting status is success, I return true which results submitting the form `<form method="POST" action="home.html">`
  [image]

Now I'm having a few questions:

1. My form POSTs the password to my `home.html`.
   I believe I have to replace the password value and add some kind of session value to the form to be able to check later if the user session is valid or not. Do I?
   **How is this done on a professional security level?**
2. I can't access the form data in my `home.html` as long as I use POST. I try to avoid using GET because professional websites don't have those ugly urls.
   [image: screenshot_form_data]
   How am I supposed to transport username + session id? Do I have to use cookies here?
   I didn't really worked with cookies so far, but since user can read cookies, I still won't add any real passwords here and replace password with a session id.
3. For my understandings: These security requirements won't change even with https. HTTPS provides a secure connection but I still won't save or store any real passwords anywhere on the client.

Comment: What happens if the user opens home.html directly? Also, what does the home.html do with the arguments? Is there a JavaScript appliction on it that can read the parameters? It seems like you are missing some conceptual knowledge. Are those really static html files that are served directly by the webserver?

Comment: why not achieve the same from server side scripting lang like PHP? As your title says "best practice for login". You can every well do it using client side but that requires lots of validation and token system to be a secured one.

Comment: @Harry OP is already talking about their backend in Perl. Why suggest a different backend technology?

Comment: Sorry missed that part :) But I was like replace ".html" with server side scripting so that we can handle the redirecting part if the user directly lands in "home" section.

Comment: @simbabque if the user opens home.html directly a popup comes up telling the user to login and redirect him to my login page. That's what 
 I'm taking the arguements for. My requirement is to use perl instead of php. So I try to do use jquery controls for the dynamic content. I'm not a straight webdeveloper, I did many sites, mostly for internal purposes and almost every time I don't had to care about security purposes. That's why I'm picking this up.

Comment: You're making your life harder than it needs to be. If you have to stick to plain CGI, I would at least use a Perl program to serve all content. That is, get rid of the .html files and make the backend decide what to send to the user. Or, if there is not a lot of logic involved, just use a .htaccess file with the login data and put that up in front of your home.html.

Comment: I already had some web-applications where I use perl only. For me it always looks like an old-fashined way to create websites. As far as I know, if I'd use PHP I'd use html files including PHP scripts for dynamical content. I try to reproduce this on perl. Even if I'm making my life harder, I don't care as long as the quality of programming is higher then before.

Comment: If you want it modern and you know Perl, you should look into some modern frameworks that work with PSGI/Plack. Start out with [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s) and then look at the various frameworks, like [Dancer2](http://perldancer.org/), [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/) or [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/). All of them have extensive documentation and a strong community. It will greatly make your life easier to use one of them instead of CGI.

Comment: I'm going to get a look into it. Never heared about any of them.